# Cleanest way to get a value from a list element

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lines from a parsed log like so:

```
parsedLog = ['20151005 09:11:14 LOG_ID 00000000', '20151005 09:11:14 LOG_ADDR 0173acc4\n    Address of log', '20151005 09:11:14 READ_CONFIG 00000105',
```

I am looking for the cleanest way to extract the value `0173acc4` from the second element in the list based off a the string `LOG_ADDR` (i.e. the key) (reason being is the log will not always be consistent).

I currently am using the following one liner:

```
filter(lambda line: 'LOG_ADDR' in line, parsedLog)[0].split('\n')[-8:]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use regex.

```
for line in parsedlog:
    if 'LOG_ADDR' in line:
        print re.search(r'\S+(?=\n)', line).group()
```

`\S+` matches one or more non-space characters. So this `\S+(?=\n)` would match one or more non-space characters only if it's followed by a newline character. Lookaheads are assertions which won't consume any single char but asserts whether a match is possible or not.

or

Change the `print` stmt to,

```
print re.search(r'\bLOG_ADDR\s+(\S+)', line).group(1)
```

or

```
>>> for line in parsedLog:
    if 'LOG_ADDR' in line:
        s = line.split()
        for i,j in enumerate(s):
            if j == 'LOG_ADDR':
                print(s[i+1])


0173acc4
>>>
```

or

```
>>> for line in parsedLog:
    if 'LOG_ADDR' in line:
        s = line.split()
        print s[s.index('LOG_ADDR')+1]


0173acc4
```

Comment: You could also do split after  `if 'LOG_ADDR' in line:` then `line.index('LOG_ADDR')`  rather than use the for loop. Assuming it's consistent

Comment: @SirParselot ya, this is same as other answer. But we need to avoid more num of splits in list comprehension.

Comment: Ah that wasn't up when I mentioned it but yes that is what I was thinking. The regex is the best of the methods shown

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain how the regex works to grab the value in the first example you provided?

Comment: Isn't using in and search a bit redundant?

Comment: then `m = re.search(r'\bLOG_ADDR\s+(\S+)(?=\n)', line); if m: print m.group(1)`

Comment: @AvinashRaj  How about if the line does not contain the new line character at the end? Is there a regex that can fulfill both requirements?

Comment: then try the second option

Answer (score 1):

With list comprehension:

```
[i.split()[i.split().index("LOG_ADDR")+1] for i in parsedLog if "LOG_ADDR" in i][0]
'0173acc4'
```

or expanded, which is more clean and more readable, and faster as `split()` is not executed twice:

```
for i in parsedLog:
    if "LOG_ADDR" in i:
        line_split = i.split()
        index_addr = line_split.index("LOG_ADDR") + 1
        print line_split[index_addr]
```

It gets the value after `LOG_ADDR`, assuming that condition is constant.

`line_split.index("LOG_ADDR") + 1` gives you the index in the splitted line to which we add one to get the next item

Answer (score 1):

```
parsedLog = ['20151005 09:11:14 LOG_ID 00000000', '20151005 09:11:14 LOG_ADDR 0173acc4\n    Address of log', '20151005 09:11:14 READ_CONFIG 00000105']


print(re.search(r'\bLOG_ADDR\W+(\w+)', ''.join(parsedLog), re.MULTILINE).groups(1)[0])

0173acc4
```